# Why am I getting an arm64 error in Swift even on brand new projects?

Tags: ios, swift

I was working on an app with Xcode 11.6 connecting my phone to test run when I got an error:

```
<unknown>:0: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk'
<unknown>:0: error: unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios13.5'
```

After this happened, all of the simulators and the option to test the app on my phone disappeared [(see top left of screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8meHl.jpg).
I know that this is not an error on the specific app I was working on because I can no longer run anything on Xcode. When starting a new project this error immediately causes the build to fail.

I am brand new to coding so I would appreciate a low-intelligence explanation. Thanks!